# Xcode error "Profile doesn't include the beta-reports-active entitlement" for adhoc profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have valid adhoc provisioning profile, when I set that profile Xcode throws error "Profile doesn't include the beta-reports-active entitlement", and I don't know, why Xcode is giving this issue as adhoc profile doesn't contains beta-reports-active entitlement. If anyone has any idea about this issue then please help.

Comment: Please select "Automatically select signing" from Target->General

Comment: But I do not have developer account credentials to auto-sign in

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting this error, By mistake you choose different provision profile in Signing (Distribution) and Signing (Release). As you will made same provision for both, the error will gone.

Comment: Same question, but not resolved by any method. Xcode does not have Signing(Distribution) item, how can it be here?

Comment: Have you Apple developer account?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the method that : Bulid setting - Signing -Provisioning Profile(Debug) using Development provisioning profile , and Provisioning Profile(Release) using Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile. hope helpful for you .

Answer (score 0):

I have met a similar situation. The issue was with I am mistakenly selected `app-store` provisioning profile instead of `ad-hoc` at the time of `archive`.

`Archive` again with corresponding provisioning profile resolved my issue. Hope this will help someone